# Convert an Excel table from one structure to the other

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

## Original table

I have this table in Excel or LibreOffice.

| Unit number | Type | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Object | Top |
| 1 | Object | Bottom |
| 1 | Object | Left |
| 1 | Object | Right |
| 1 | Object | Back |
| 1 | Object | Front |
| 1 | Property | Right-Fixed |
| 1 | Property | Left-Fixed |
| 1 | Property | 4-legs |

## New table

I want to convert this table to a new one. I want to keep only the rows with the *Type* equal to *Object* and apply the *Properties* as new columns. Like below.

| Unit number | Type | Name | Right-fixed | Left-fixed | 4-legs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Object | Top |  |  |  |
| 1 | Object | Bottom |  |  | True |
| 1 | Object | Left |  | True |  |
| 1 | Object | Right | True |  |  |
| 1 | Object | Back |  |  |  |
| 1 | Object | Front |  |  |  |

## Question

How can I do that in Excel or LibreOffice? My options are:

- Formula-based approaches.

  - Will it get too complex?
- VBA macro programming.

  - Is it overkill for this problem?

I'd appreciate any hint or help.

## Note

Above, I have shown just the *Unit number* of `1` as a sample. But unit numbers could continue, like `2`, `3`, and more.

Comment: I'm studying the links provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71584381/3405291). Those are helpful user guides for Calc Basic code.

Comment: How you transform to the new table isn't clearly defined. For example, how did you determine that "4-legs" property is for Object "Bottom"? Without a deterministic way, there is no way to program an answer.
Lastly, the decision to program or not depends on how often you need to do this and how much data you have.

Comment: @H3coder The bottom side is related to the *legs* since the legs are attached to the bottom :) Some 3D boxes/units with 6 sides are listed by the tables. Along with their properties.

Comment: @H3coder If I do this conversion often and frequently, and I have lots of units/data, then does it make sense to go for the VBA macro programming?

Comment: Do you have a mapping table to define the relationship between objects ( 6 sides ) and properties ( eg. 4-legs ) ?

Comment: @taller I don't have a mapping table at the moment. But it's a great idea to compose one :)

Comment: Yes, If you have often/frequent need, yes, macro makes sense. taller's proposal to use a mapping table makes sense, otherwise you are relying on assumed knowledge of relationship of object and properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add a mapping table define the relationship between objects and properties
- The sequence of object names for each unit may different.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long, i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long, sHeader As String
    Dim dataSht As Worksheet, mapSht As Worksheet
    Dim oDicMap As Object, oDicCol As Object
    Dim oDicRow As Object, oDic As Object, sKey
    Const BASE_COLS = 3 ' The first 3 cols on output table are fixed
    Set dataSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify as needed
    Set mapSht = Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' Load mapping table
    Set oDicMap = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arrData = mapSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        oDicMap(arrData(i, 1)) = arrData(i, 2)
    Next i
    ' Load source data
    Set oDicCol = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arrData = dataSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    iR = BASE_COLS
    ' Get header names of output
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 2) = "Property" Then
            iR = iR + 1
            oDicCol(arrData(i, 3)) = iR
        End If
    Next i
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oDicRow = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Output table header
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1 To iR)
    arrRes(1, 1) = "Unit"
    arrRes(1, 2) = "Type"
    arrRes(1, 3) = "Name"
    For Each sKey In oDicCol.Keys
        arrRes(1, oDicCol(sKey)) = sKey
    Next
    iR = 1
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        ' Add a new row for Object
        If arrData(i, 2) = "Object" Then
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(iR, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
            arrRes(iR, 3) = arrData(i, 3)
            sKey = arrData(i, 1) & arrData(i, 3)
            oDicRow(sKey) = iR
        ElseIf arrData(i, 2) = "Property" Then
            ' Insert True
            If oDicMap.exists(arrData(i, 3)) And oDicCol.exists(arrData(i, 3)) Then
                sKey = arrData(i, 1) & oDicMap(arrData(i, 3))
                If oDicRow.exists(sKey) Then
                    arrRes(oDicRow(sKey), oDicCol(arrData(i, 3))) = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' Write ouput to sheet
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(iR, UBound(arrRes, 2)).Value = arrRes
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Did you test your macro code by MS Excel or LibreOffice Calc? I'm learning LibreOffice Basic coding at the moment.

Comment: I just need to convert your VBA to LibreOffice Basic. I'm on it.

Comment: It is Excel VBA.

Comment: Unfortunately, conversion to OOo Basic isn't very straight forward... a few hints:
1) Easy: There are no "Range", "Worksheet" types. Use Object or Variant.
2) Easy: Change Sheets function to: ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("Sheet1")
3) Med: There is no dictionary object. This [post has mention of collection](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2953&hilit=Collections+in+OOoBasic). I haven't tried it though...
4) Hard: Range service doesn't seem to automatically give continuous range. You may need to build your own.
5) Easy: Array size need to be declared.

Comment: @H3coder Thanks, very helpful. I just started converting to OOo Basic. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: @H3coder The OOo Basic collections are explained [here](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/assets/downloads/7/LibOBasic_09_StructDataTypes_Flat_A4_EN_v101.pdf).

Comment: @Megidd Dictionary class module (w/o windows scripting lib) might be helpful for you.  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary

Comment: Turned out there is also [dictionary support in LO by loading a ScriptForge Module](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/hr/text/sbasic/shared/03/sf_dictionary.html?&DbPAR=SHARED&System=WIN), but I think collections is sufficient enough in this case.

Comment: @H3coder The problem with `Collection` is that if I have `Dim Prop As String` and `Dim Obj As String` then I cannot do `map(Prop) = Obj` or even `map.Add(Obj, Prop)` for some reason.

Comment: `map(Prop) = Obj` is not a valid format, you should get a run time error with this.  I just tried other parts in a small sub, all seems to work for me. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` then the following formula should work as per the tags posted. The following formula is a single input dynamic array formula.*

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:C10,
     _object, FILTER(_data,INDEX(_data,,2)="Object"),
     _property, UNIQUE(TOROW(TAKE(FILTER(_data,INDEX(_data,,2)="Property"),,-1)),1),
     _rows, ROWS(_object),
     _cols, COLUMNS(_property),
     _name, SWITCH(LEFT(_property,2),"Ri","Ri","Le","Le","4-","Bo"),
     _convert, HSTACK(_object,MAKEARRAY(_rows,_cols,LAMBDA(r,c,N(INDEX(LEFT(TAKE(_object,,-1),2),r)=INDEX(_name,c))))),
     _headers, HSTACK(A1:C1,_property),
     VSTACK(_headers,_convert))
```

---

- `_data` --> variable used for the data range, excluding the headers,
- `_object` --> Using `FILTER()` returns the range which consists of only `object`
- `_property` --> Using `FILTER()` returns the range which consists of only `property`, and then taking the last column of that range with unique values transformed into columns from rows.
- `_rows` --> Using the `ROWS()` to get number of object rows count.
- `_cols` --> Using `COLUMNS()` to get the number of property columns count.
- `_name` --> Using the `SWITHC()` function amending the names so as to match with the properties.
- `_convert` --> This uses a combination of `HSTACK()` for one part and `MAKEARRAY()` for another part. So the `MAKEARRAY()` is returning an array with  `n` rows and `n` columns based on the custom `LAMBDA()` calculation applied, so what it does it just tries to do a `BOOLEAN LOGIC` and returns `1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE` which is custom formatted as `[=1]TRUE;;`. While using the `HSTACK()` we are combining the return value of `MAKEARRAY()` as well as the variable `_object`.
- `_headers` --> as the name defines returning the respective headers for the array.
- Lastly, using `VSTACK()` to append both the arrays, here `_headers` with `_convert`.

---

One small change can be done by removing the `_name` variable if you are sure about the property labels then,

• Instead of this

```
N(INDEX(LEFT(TAKE(_object,,-1),2),r)=INDEX(_name,c))
```

---

• Use this in place of that. remember to remove the `_name` variable first.

```
N(INDEX(TAKE(_object,,-1),r)=INDEX(TEXTBEFORE(SUBSTITUTE(_property,"4","Bottom"),"-"),c))
```

---

**Edit:**

Here is an updated answer:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, A1:C19,
     _Mapping, {
         "Right-Fixed", "Right";
         "Left-Fixed", "Left";
         "4-Legs", "Bottom";
         "Front-Fixed", "Front";
         "Back-Fixed", "Back";
         "Folder", "Top"
      },
     _Headers, HSTACK(
         TAKE(_Data, 1),
         TOROW(
             TAKE(_Mapping, , 1)
         )
      ),
     _Object, FILTER(
         _Data,
         INDEX(_Data, , 2) =
             "Object"
     ),
     _Rows, ROWS(_Object),
     _Columns, COLUMNS(
         DROP(_Headers, , 3)
     ),
     _Matched, MAKEARRAY(_Rows,_Columns,LAMBDA(r,c, LET(
     _Property, FILTER(INDEX(_Data,,3),(INDEX(_Object,r,1)=INDEX(_Data,,1))*(INDEX(_Data,,2)="Property")),
     _MappedProps, VLOOKUP(_Property,_Mapping,2,0),
     _MappedObj, VLOOKUP(INDEX(DROP(_Headers,,3),c),_Mapping,2,0),
      N(OR((_MappedProps=_MappedObj)*(_MappedProps=INDEX(_Object,r,3))))))),
     _Merged, HSTACK(
        _Object,
        _Matched
     ),
     VSTACK(_Headers, _Merged)
  )
```

---

Comment: I'm going to use macro programming. Your approach is an alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas should work fine. You can just sort the table by the Type column, and then delete all the rows that don't have 'Object'. Then you just need to add the new columns, i.e. 'Right-fixed', etc. and use some simple formulas to return either "" or 'True', i.e., `IF([Name] = "Right-Fixed", "True, "")`.

Once you have those columns set up and the formulas returning either True or "", you can copy the columns and paste as value, to hard-code the results, and then you can delete the 'Name' column.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out the VBA macro development. I think the macro might be more manageable down the road. Not sure whether its maintainability overcomes its development effort.